# WCF service - Client Uml class diagram

Tags: wcf, uml

I have implemented a three layer web site project. Business layer is composed of a WCF service. Presentation layer uses this WCF service. Data access layer is used by WCF. The project is working. But I have a difficulty of showing the relation between WCF service and its client in a UML class diagram with visual studio 2010. I'm seeing classes and interfaces on architecture explorer but I couldn't establish the relation in class diagram.

Have you solve this before or Have you came across any tutorial or example on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I generally find it best to keep them separate, because essentially the service and the consuming client application are separate applications.  The service's diagram shouldn't have any information about the client on it, other than the fact that clients are able to connect to it through "the cloud."  And the client's diagram should just show the service as a kind of external dependency with an API to which it connects.